# Is possible to use IN () to find INTERSECT

Tags: mysql

When I use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1, 2, 3, 3, ..., 1000)
```

It is taken to be

```
... WHERE column = 1 OR column = 2 OR ... OR column = 1000
```

But I would like this

```
... WHERE column = 1 AND column = 2 AND ... AND column = 1000
```

in column there are id parameters. Is there an easy way to solve this?

It is possible, bacause it is table with m:n relationship. One product can have many paramameters.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productparametervalues` (
`f_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`f_parameterValue_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`f_product_id`,`f_parameterValue_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

Comment: My answer doesn't take into account the possibility that you're looking for the `OR` solution with the added constraint that rows must be present in the resultset for _all_ of these values; is that the case? Can you clarify your question? Explaining what you want to do with a code sample that -- by your own admission -- does not achieve that goal is pretty useless!

Comment: That's a nonsense - what are you expecting to get using 'WHERE column = 1 AND column = 2 AND ... AND column = 1000'?

Comment: I'm expecting products which have choose parameters. Why it is nonsense?

Comment: @tomasr: For any record, the field `column` has one value. You're trying to test for rows each having multiple values simultaneously. That's trivially identifiable as nonsense. **Please expand on your functional requirements**, using _words_ and _example data_.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Everything is describe, in that table are in m:n relationship product_id and parameterVaue_id. That mean that one product could have thousand parametrs and one parameter could belong to thousand products. In that case it has sense and solution wrote **Joe Stefanelli** bellow.

Comment: @tomasr Cos one filed cannot be equal to 1 and 2 at the same time.

Comment: @tomasr: No, you're missing _words_ and _example data_. The problem requirement is under-specified. Joe was very clever and managed to fill in the gaps in what you wanted, but the question should still be amended so that it makes sense to future visitors.

Comment: @Dmitry do you know m:n relationship?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: sorry I can't to explain it better. I think that sql command create of table I talking about is enough. From that is seeing that is m:n relationship and I wrote that to.

Comment: @tomasr So far I've only dealt with s:m, but I've got what you're saying.

Comment: @tomasr: As I said before, the only part of your question that attempts to explain what you're trying to do is a piece of code that _doesn't_ achieve it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: Modified my answer to match the table schema that was added to the question.

You can use a GROUP BY/COUNT DISTINCT to achieve this. The value tested on the HAVING COUNT should be equal to the number of items that are included in the IN clause.

```
SELECT f_product_id
    FROM productparametervalues
    WHERE f_parameterValue_id IN (1, 2, 3, ..., 1000)
    GROUP BY f_product_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT f_parameterValue_id) = 1000;
```

Comment: Firstly I don't now how many parameters each product has, each one has different count of parameters. And secondly I can't group by primary key in table parameters. I need to find all products include those without parameters.

Comment: @tomasr: But you're seeking the products which have *all* of the parameters you specify in the `IN` clause, right? You must know how many values you intend to include in the `IN` clause each time.

Comment: Yes you are right I know that, but I can't group how you suggest. I grou by product_id in table products.

Comment: @tomasr: Notice that I modified my answer to match the table schema you added. I have `GROUP BY f_product_id`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

There is no syntax to do this because the clause would always evaluate to `FALSE`; how could one field have multiple values like that?

Comment: @Dmitry: I posted this answer _before_ you wrote your comment. "16 minutes ago" vs "24 minutes ago". _You_ copied _me_. Nice try, though.